# How much memory does consume one notification event in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, events, callback, notifications, queue

I read an article, titled
**Event Monitor Process: Architecture and Known Issues (Doc ID 105067.1)**:

> ... In 10.1 onwards the procedures DBMS_AQADM.GET_WATERMARK and
> DBMS_AQADM.SET_WATERMARK are available to set the amount of memory
> available for notification events ...

Can someone explain me what is the amount of memory for just one notification event? How much memory precisely consumes one notification event?
I need to know that, because I want to predict an amount of memory for all notification events during intensive workload on Oracle database with a big amount of queue messages, in situation, when each message needs to be processed by notification callback procedure.  If i will know that, I will be able to set
**dbms_aqadm.set_watermark** to appropriate value.

Comment: I want to mention - it would be very helpful to have a statistics entry in v$sesstat just for AQ current watermark consumption...

Comment: Surely that will depend on the size of the notification message which is something you control.  If you are enqueuing a message with a single integer as the payload, that's going to take vastly less memory than if you are enqueuing a message whose payload is a large JSON document.  For most "how much of resource x will workload y require" questions, it's better to benchmark your system and see.  Run 1% of y, run 2% of y, run 10% of y, etc., measure resource consumption, and see how the workload scales

Comment: Thanks, Justin. I want to clarify: If I enqueue a message to a queue without notification callback - there will be no notification event raise, right? Because EMON has to do nothing with an usual enqueue.